# Android Studio 2.3.1 - Random Shutdown Error

Tags: android-studio-2.3

I am new to Android programming. I have an issue: my PC shutdown while I was working on a program.

When I turned it on I got all kinds of errors. I tried other programs that I created in my lesson (which I took from Internet), but none of them work now.  They all give me many errors.

For example:

[image: image code sample]

I think when the PC shutdown I might have lost something, but I uninstalled Android and reinstalled and I get the same thing.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: To improve the quality of the Question copy and paste your code into the Question and format the code as a code sample rather than giving us a link to an image that is stored elsewhere.  Links to images are good for including in a Question information that can't be readily included, such as diagrams and samples of graphical output.

Comment: The reason I loaded a Picture was to show the red errors... the code is not the issue... the questions is why am I getting all these errors when the should not be there...  That is the question....   for example TextView is imported and there is an error on that line, could there be an issue with the imports libraries maybe being corrupted?  although I Uninstalled studio and reloaded it... is there an option to repair the installation? when I remove the program are there some folders which need to be deleted manually.. to make a clean install? Those are the questions,  the code, not the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I'm fix
1. uninstall android studio
2. install new android studio and skd again
3. open android project 
4. File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart